# Why doesn't redirection work with Flask and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, flask

I'm programming in Python and I'm using the Flask framework. I'm having a problem with the `redirect()` function. It simply doesn't work for some unknown reason. It doesn't cast an error, or throw an error into the console. It doesn't mention anything in the terminal, either. I need it to work for my login system where if you input to register doesn't match the validation, to redirect you back to the page and display the error (through sessions.)

I've tried using different ways I've found on the internet and by reading source code. I've tried using `app.redirect()` method instead of `flask.redirect()` the global function. Here is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect
from flask_session import Session
from security_manager import password_hash, password_check
from validate_email_address import validate_email
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<!DOCTYPE html><a href=\"/signup\">Redirect to Sign-up page</a>"


@app.route("/signup")
def signup():
    try:
        message = session["signup_error"]
        return render_template("signup.htm") + (
            "" if "signup_error" not in session else
            "<p style=\"color:red;\">" + message + "</p>"
        )
    except KeyError:
        return render_template("signup.htm")


@app.route("/control-signup", methods=["POST"])
def control_signup():
    display_name = request.form["display_name"]  # Use .args for GET requests,
    # .form for POST ones
    display_name = secure_signal(display_name)

    # Validating username (handle)
    username = request.form["username"]
    if not username_valid(username):
        session["signup_error"] = "Username can only include lowercase" \
                                  " letters a&ndash;z, uppercase letters" \
                                  " A&ndash;Z, digits 0&ndash;9 or an" \
                                  " underscore and must be 4 to 16" \
                                  " characters long."
        redirect("/signup")
    elif not username_available(username):
        session["signup_error"] = "Username is already taken."
        redirect("/signup")

    # Validating E-Mail address
    email = request.form["email"]

    if not validate_email(email):
        session["signup_error"] = "E-Mail address appears to be invalid."
        redirect("/signup")

    # Checking if password confirmation is correct
    password = request.form["password"]
    password_confirmation = request.form["password_confirmation"]

    if password != password_confirmation:
        session["signup_error"] = "Passwords don't match."
        redirect("/signup")

    #  Checking if password is strong enough.
    if not 8 <= len(password):
        session["signup_error"] = "Password must at least be 8 characters" \
                                  " long."
        redirect("/signup")

    digits = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    has_digit = False

    for digit in digits:
        if digit in password:  # If the password has a digit.
            has_digit = True
            break

    if not has_digit:
        session["signup_error"] = "Password must include a digit."
        redirect("/signup", code=302)

    # Everything is fine. Create the account.
    users_db = json.load(open("users.json", "r"))

    # Hashing the password
    hashed_password = password_hash(password)

    user = {
        "username": username,
        "email": email,
        "password": hashed_password,
        "display_name": display_name,
        "bio": ""
    }

    users_db.append(user)
    with open("users.json", "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(users_db, indent=4))

    return render_template("signup_complete.htm")


@app.route("/log-in")
def log_in():
    if "login_error" in session:
        return render_template("log-in.htm") + ("<span style=\"color:red\">" +
                                                session["login_error"] +
                                                "</span>")
    else:
        return render_template("log-in.htm")


@app.route("/control-login", methods=["POST"])
def control_login():
    email_or_username = request.form["email_or_username"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    login_meth = request.form["login_meth"]

    user_db = json.load(open("users.json", "r"))

    for user in user_db:
        if user["email" if login_meth == "email" else "username"]\
                                == email_or_username and\
                                password_check(password, user["password"]):
            session["is_logged_in"] = True

    if session["is_logged_in"]:
        return "<h1>Successfully logged you in</h1>"
    else:
        session["login_error"] = "Username, E-Mail or password incorrect."
        redirect("/log-in")


def secure_signal(message: str) -> str:
    return (message
            .replace("&", "&amp;")
            .replace("<", "&lt;")
            .replace(">", "&gt;")
            .replace("'", "&apos;")
            .replace("\"", "&quot;")
            )


def username_valid(username: str) -> bool:
    """
    :param username: Username you want to validate.
    :return: Boolean "True" if the username is valid and "False if the
    username is invalid
    """
    # Checking if the username has illegal characters
    legal_characters = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
                        "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                        "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
                        "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
                        "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2",
                        "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "_")

    for letter in username:
        if letter not in legal_characters:
            return False

    # Checking if username is short/long enough
    if not 4 <= len(username) <= 16:
        return False


def username_available(username: str) -> bool:
    # Checking if the username is already taken
    users_db = json.load(open("users.json", "r"))

    for user in users_db:
        if user["username"].lower() == username.lower():
            # I type ".lower()" because I don't want the usernames to be
            # case-sensitive.
            return False

    del users_db

    return True


def email_available(email: str) -> bool:
    # Checking if the username is already taken
    users_db = json.load(open("users.json", "r"))

    for user in users_db:
        if user["email"].lower() == email.lower():
            # I type ".lower()" because I don't want the usernames to be
            # case-sensitive.
            return False

    del users_db

    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You need to return it e.g. `return redirect("/signup")`.

Comment: @kobuz Thank you for the quick answer. Now everything works fine.